# How to use while loop with text data and create new data set

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create two different datasets based on this dataset with text data.

```
id <- c(24, 24, 56, 56, 56, 56, 92, 92, 92)
visit_id <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3)
location <- c('Hospital', 'Hospital', 'Clinic', 'Hospital', 'Hospital', 
    'Hospital', 'Clinic', 'Hospital', 'Clinic')
data <- data.frame(id, visit_id, location)
```

For the first data set, my aim is to create a dummy variable that identifies patients whose first visit was at clinic and assign '1' to those who meet this criteria. So it would look something like this...

```
id <- c(24, 56, 92)
exclude <- c(0, 1, 1)
data1 <- data.frame(id, exclude)
```

For the second dataset, I would like to identify those who have a record of visiting either the hospital OR clinic and assign them with '0'.

```
id <- c(24, 56, 92)
exclude <- c(1, 0, 0)
data2 <- data.frame(id, exclude)
```

I am not familiar with loops and have some experience using conditional operators on numerical data.

Comment: the exclude means remove? if so why not exclude 92 from dataset1 since the id visited clinic first just like id 56 has exclude=?1

Comment: FYI, this isn't an exercise in loops. It's an exercise in selecting observations that meet a specific criteria.

Comment: What you presented for the desired output is wrong. `id == 92` has visited `Clinic` for the first visit but you identified it as `0` in `data1`.

Comment: Hi @Masoud , I just caught that. Thanks!

Comment: I am on my phone but I realized for 5 out of 12 questions that stackoverflow app shows, you accepted an answer for none. And putting my answer asside there are pretty good answers for the other ones. Please take some time and accept the best answer in your opinion. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% filter(visit_id == 1) %>% 
  mutate(exclude = if_else(location=="Clinic",1,0)) %>% select(id,exclude)

#   id exclude
# 1 24       0
# 2 56       1
# 3 92       1


data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(exclude = ifelse(length(unique(location))==1,1,0)) %>% 
  select(id,exclude) %>% filter(row_number()==1)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#      id exclude
#   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1    24       1
# 2    56       0
# 3    92       0
```